# TSLint - Remove whitespace on decorator

Tags: typescript, tslint

I'm getting a TSLint error in VSCode, complaining that there is no white space after the "at" symbol in a decorator.

I have:

```
@Input()
```

but TSLint wants me to write:

```
@ Input()
```

What rule do I need to adjust in TS lint to remove this whitespace (ideally without affecting the whitespace around other elements)

Using tslint 5.11.0 and Typescript 2.3.3.

Here is my tslint.json:

```
{
  "rulesDirectory": [
    "node_modules/codelyzer"
  ],
  "extends": [
    "rxjs-tslint-rules"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "callable-types": true,
    "class-name": true,
    "comment-format": [
      true,
      "check-space"
    ],
    "curly": true,
    "eofline": true,
    "forin": true,
    "import-blacklist": [
      true,
      "rxjs"
    ],
    "import-spacing": true,
    "indent": [
      true,
      "spaces"
    ],
    "interface-over-type-literal": true,
    "label-position": true,
    "max-line-length": [
      true,
      140
    ],
    "member-access": false,
    "member-ordering": [
      true,
      {
        "order": ["static-field", "instance-field", "constructor", "static-method", "instance-method"]
      }
    ],
    "no-arg": true,
    "no-bitwise": true,
    "no-console": [
      true,
      "debug",
      "info",
      "time",
      "timeEnd",
      "trace"
    ],
    "no-construct": true,
    "no-debugger": true,
    "no-duplicate-variable": true,
    "no-empty": false,
    "no-empty-interface": true,
    "no-eval": true,
    "no-inferrable-types": [
      true,
      "ignore-params"
    ],
    "no-shadowed-variable": true,
    "no-string-literal": false,
    "no-string-throw": true,
    "no-switch-case-fall-through": true,
    "no-trailing-whitespace": true,
    "no-unused-expression": true,
    "no-use-before-declare": true,
    "no-var-keyword": true,
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false,
    "one-line": [
      true,
      "check-open-brace",
      "check-catch",
      "check-else",
      "check-whitespace"
    ],
    "prefer-const": true,
    "quotemark": [
      true,
      "single"
    ],
    "radix": true,
    "semicolon": [
      true,
      "always"
    ],
    "triple-equals": [
      true,
      "allow-null-check"
    ],
    "typedef-whitespace": [
      true,
      {
        "call-signature": "nospace",
        "index-signature": "nospace",
        "parameter": "nospace",
        "property-declaration": "nospace",
        "variable-declaration": "nospace"
      }
    ],
    "unified-signatures": true,
    "variable-name": false,
    "whitespace": [
      true,
      "check-branch",
      "check-decl",
      "check-module",
      "check-separator",
      "check-type",
      "check-typecast",
      "check-type-operator",
      "check-preblock"
    ],
    "directive-selector": [
      true,
      "attribute",
      "cc",
      "camelCase"
    ],
    "component-selector": [
      true,
      "element",
      "cc",
      "kebab-case"
    ],
    "use-input-property-decorator": true,
    "use-output-property-decorator": true,
    "use-host-property-decorator": true,
    "use-life-cycle-interface": true,
    "use-pipe-transform-interface": true,
    "rxjs-add": {
      "options": [{
        "allowElsewhere": false,
        "allowUnused": false,
        "file": "./src/rxjs-imports.ts"
      }],
      "severity": "error"
    },
    "rxjs-no-unused-add": {
      "severity": "error"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your `tslint.json` settings, TSLint version, and TypeScript version?

Comment: @Josh sure, edited the question

Answer (score 1):

When VSCode highlights the error, it also tells you the rule name which is causing that error.

Add following to your package.json under scripts.

```
"lint": "tslint \"app/**/*.ts\"",
"lintfix": "tslint --fix app/**/*.ts{,x}"
```

You can run following to find the issues in your code:

```
npm run lint
```

You can auto-fix the issues using following command:

```
npm run lintfix
```

Once you know the rule name, you can disable it in tslint.json file.